# How to check to see if the next line is blank and ignore it (2D Array C)?

Tags: c

In my program it has a predefined constant value for both the **ROWS** and the **COLUMNS** of the 2D array. However, I want it to go the max number of rows and columns & skip over any blank or empty lines & then print the "grades" (while ignoring the empty 30th line) to the screen. I've tried incorporating fgets and sscan, probably poorly, but only got a strange set of numbers. My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 30
#define COLUMN 4

int main()
{
FILE *ip;

ip = fopen("input.txt", "r");
int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;


int i, j;
int grades[ROWS][COLUMN];

for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    count2 = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
    {
        int num;
        if(fscanf(ip, "%d", &num) != '\0')
        {
            grades[i][j] = num;
            count2++;
        }
        else
        {
            count2 = 0;
        }
    }
    if(count2 != 0)
    {
        count1++;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
    {
        printf("Student %d Grade %d: %d\n", i+1, j+1, grades[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

fclose(ip);

return 0;
}
```

My infile looks like (29 rows instead of my max which is "30"):

```
33 0 97 40
50 61 96 92
98 68 61 65
91 29 48 5
14 30 97 11
22 0 7 81
96 55 9 39
67 39 83 97
5 18 67 9
85 53 33 73
62 58 24 70
91 97 69 33
40 1 86 92
83 26 74 67
53 4 18 20
49 67 98 64
62 39 27 56
26 9 43 1
46 73 48 68
34 48 38 71
21 32 24 6
50 27 79 96
1 0 59 81
58 34 95 8
48 91 2 77
90 99 68 20
43 99 94 40
4 65 29 1
70 34 83 74
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Repeats the last num before it]

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that the assignment states that there is a MAXIMUM of 30 students with 4 grades each, however the number of actual students are not specified. So it could be 29 rows, 26 rows, 20 rows, 30 rows or 15 rows. However, there will ALWAYS be 4 grades for each student.

Comment: If your infile has 29 rows then do not try to read 30. Initialise the array instead.

Comment: One second I will edit it to clarify.

Comment: Your input has "blank or empty lines". So you must read the file with `fgets` and apply `sscanf` to each input line, taking action on the return value from `sscanf`, which, as the man page will tell you, is the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: So basically I want the program to run until EOF.

Comment: `fscanf()` will return `EOF` when it reaches EOF. Check for that in your loop.

Comment: `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, ip) != NULL) { /* apply sscanf to buffer */ }`

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/8nJOt8)